# Yocto cannot copy files to root path of rootfs

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

I have an issue with only copying files in to rootfs with yocto build I don't need to compile those files its some binaries and .sh files.
When I run bitbake  the error says that it cannot install the package  and next warnings are:
at the log file :

> ERROR: Unable to install packages. Command
> '/home/ubuntu20/openstlinux-5.4-dunfell-mp1-20-11-12/build-openstlinuxcv-stm32mp1-ground4-mx/tmp-glibc/work/stm32mp1_ground4_mx-ostl-linux-gnueabi/st-image-minimal/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-get  install --force-yes --allow-unauthenticated --no-remove apt csr
> csr-mergefiles dpkg packagegroup-base-extended packagegroup-core-boot
> packagegroup-core-eclipse-debug packagegroup-core-ssh-dropbear
> packagegroup-core-tools-profile packagegroup-framework-core
> packagegroup-framework-core-base packagegroup-framework-minimal-tools
> packagegroup-framework-minimal-tools-base powerbutton resize-helper
> run-postinsts' returned 100:

and lots of outputs of this:

> ```
> Selecting previously unselected package util-linux-whereis:armhf.
> Preparing to unpack .../util-linux-whereis_2.35.1-r0.0_armhf.deb ...
> Unpacking util-linux-whereis:armhf (2.35.1-r0.0) ... dpkg: warning:
> overriding problem because --force enabled: dpkg: warning: package
> architecture (armhf) does not match system (amd64)
> ```

if I add `PACKAGE_ARCH = "armhf"`

there's the error

> no manifest generated for this recipe

Maybe someone had this issue before?

```
SUMMARY = "csr copy the application files "
DESCRIPTION = "Recipe created by bitbake-layers"

LICENSE="CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM=""

inherit bin_package

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "bash"


# PACKAGE_ARCH = "armhf"

# change this URI if you plan to fork the repository or use an alternate repository
SRC_URI = "git://git@#############.git;protocol=ssh"
# this SRCREV determines the branch or tag to be used
SRCREV = "master"


PV = "1.0-git-${SRCREV}"
S="${WORKDIR}/git"


do_install_append() {

  install -d ${D}/usr/csr/dwnld/
  install -d ${D}/usr/csr/files/
  install -d ${D}/usr/bin/boot_proc/
  install -d ${D}/lib/firmware/
  install -d ${D}/etc/
  install -d ${D}/etc/default/
  install -d ${D}/etc/init.d/
  install -d ${D}/etc/logrotate.d/
  install -d ${D}/etc/systemd/system/

  install -m 0755 ${S}/fs/lib/firmware/* ${D}/lib/firmware
  install -m 0755 ${S}/fs/usr/bin/boot_proc/csr_init.py ${D}/usr/bin/boot_proc/
  install -m 0755 ${S}/fs/usr/csr/dwnld/* ${D}/usr/csr/dwnld
  install -m 0755 ${S}/fs/usr/csr/files/* ${D}/usr/csr/files

  install -m 0755 ${S}/fs/etc/crontab ${D}/etc
  install -m 0755 ${S}/fs/etc/profile ${D}/etc
  install -m 0755 ${S}/fs/etc/syslog.conf ${D}/etc
  install -m 0755 ${S}/fs/etc/wpa_supplicant.CSR.conf ${D}/etc

  install -m 0755 ${S}/fs/etc/default/* ${D}/etc/default
  install -m 0755 ${S}/fs/etc/init.d/* ${D}/etc/init.d
  install -m 0755 ${S}/fs/etc/logrotate.d/* ${D}/etc/logrotate.d
  install -m 0755 ${S}/fs/etc/systemd/system/* ${D}/etc/systemd/system

}

do_package_qa (){
}

FILES_${PN} += "/usr/csr/dwnld/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/usr/csr/files/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/usr/bin/boot_proc/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/etc/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/etc/default/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/lib/firmware/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/etc/init.d/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/etc/logrotate.d/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/etc/systemd/system/*"
```

Comment: ok i founded the problem :

trying to overwrite '/etc/profile', which is also in package base-files:armhf

i have a lot of files that i trying to overwrite. how can i force overwrite them ?

Comment: As I understand you want to overwrite files that are generating by another packet? Have you got link to bb file of this packet?

Comment: yep I founded that base-files.bb are that conflicts with my recipe. So I added base-files.bbappend file that overwrites this files, But now I have another issue and it's how can I share files from my custom recipe to this bbappend recipe ?

Comment: What do you mean by "share"? Do you want to use files generated by "custom recipe" in this .bbappend? If yes, please edit the main question in the topic, after that, I can share your solution as an answer.